# Error when trying to compile in Xcode with SDL

Tags: xcode, sdl

I am trying to compile a project with SDL in Xcode and get the error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     -u command line option
```

I have the SDL.framework include along with Cocoa.framework in the Link Binary with Libraries.  I also have SDLMain.h and SDLMain.m in the project.

This is all my code:

```
#include "SDLMain.h"
#include <SDL/SDL.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you linking against `SDLmain`?

Answer (score 1):

int main has to look like this:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

get rid of the const

Comment: The reason for this is that SDLMain has a macro that replaces int main(int, char**) with int SDL_Main(int, char**) so that it can run its setup code first. If your main declaration doesn't match what the macro expects, it won't compile. Similarly, int main(){} won't work either.

Comment: I think this should be simplified to give a little more leeway here.

Answer (score 0):

It tool a quite long time until I got SDL and Xcode running. So, don't care. :-)

I uploaded [here](http://www.michaeldorner.de/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/SDL_Template.zip) a simple SDL template for Xcode 4.5 and Mac OS X 10.7 and 10.8 (also using OpenGL 3.2 Core Profile possible). Step by Step instructions:

1. Download [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL-1.2.15.dmg) (at the moment version 1.2.15)
2. Open the downloaded .dmg file
3. copy the `SDL.framework` into `/Library/Frameworks/`
4. Done. You can use the Xcode template (you should see a red area):
   [image]

Further details and an image on my [Blog](http://www.michaeldorner.de/?p=2644) (only german, sorry).